# Getting the cursor's current position on the screen in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, position, cursor, escaping, ascii

Does anyone know how to get the cursor's current position on the screen in SWI-Prolog? I have looked up ASCII escape code sequences, however, I am still confused on how to implement this in Prolog.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can, at least with what's in the box, but you can move to specific positions using [tty.pl](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/tty.pl?show=src#tty_clear/0) which is included. Try using `tty_goto` or calling `format('~Thello', [goto(20,20)])`

Comment: you can use XPCE which has graphics possibilities